# Angularjs - Getter and Setter and databinding multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cant seem to grasp this method of databinding controllers via a service. Reading posts on this website, people seem to recomend to stay away from $watch due to overhead. So I see alot of people using promises but cant seem to get the initial get data to work.

My Signle page application has 2 tables on 2 seperate controllers and a third controller that has a form to edit the data. I have a simple submit button that will set the new data to then re-syncing across all controllers. This is what i got so far:

First Controller

```
GDI_App.controller('first_Controller', function ($scope, Service) {

    Service.get_data();
    $scope.Current.incidents = Service.current_data(); //returns $$State;

});
```

Second controller

```
GDI_App.controller('second_Controller', function ($scope, Service) {

    Service.get_data();
    $scope.Current.incidents = Service.current_data(); //returns $$State;

});
```

Third controller that sets data on submit

```
GDI_App.controller('third_Controller', function ($scope, Service) {

   $scope.submit = Service.set_data(data);

});
```

Service

```
GDI_App.factory('Service', function($q) {

    var Current ={}
    Current.Data = [
       { "Data1": "123123", "Data2": "15437"  },
       { "Data1": "432234", "Data2": "146"  },
       { "Data1": "45654", "Data2": "3534"  },
       { "Data1": "76587", "Data2": "78978"  },
       { "Data1": "2342", "Data2": "5345878"  },
       { "Data1": "178", "Data2": "34534"  },
       { "Data1": "173838", "Data2": "354534"  },
    ];

    return{

         get_data: function(){
            return $q.when(Fake_Data)
            .then(function(data) {
                return data;
            });
        }

        set_data: function(data){
            Current.Data = data;
        }

    }
});
```

Does anyone know what i would be missing?

Comment: what is your angularjs version? And does this interaction iclude server? cause if no - you do not need promises at all

Comment: Start by looking at the error messages in the Developer Console.

Comment: Using the latest angularjs version 1.6

Answer (score 0):

For the controllers that you want to update without having to explicitly getting the data from the service, I would suggest having a separate function that gets the 'cached' value from the service that is being set by the setter.

Right now you have tied to the fetch, so essentially on each digest (if you used that call), which it'll just keep refetching that promise if you link it directly to function. So instead - use a getter and alias the call to a scoped model in the controller.

The way you have it, it only gets it on the controller load and doesn't know when to update/grab that model unless you used a watch.

```
$scope.display = Service.get;
```

In the view, just do

```
<div ng-repeat="mystuff in display()"></div>
```

So once the value is updated  by whatever other service it'll just update on the next digest.

Comment: Thanks but this wont work in my case. I need to get this working via the controller/service method due to my setup.

Comment: How would this not work?  You do a get in the two controllers - that reference the model directly that's being set from the fetch?

Comment: What i meant is with my current setup this solution would not be compatible. Thanks anyways.

Comment: How is your current set up not compatible?

Comment: You do realize it'll get on the digest right?  The way you have it, you're just getting the value when the controller loads - on init, forcing a watch. You could emit and then update the controllers when the value is updated in the service, or do the above. Otherwise, good luck.